# A function to display contents of 1 or 2 dimensional array of any type

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

I needed to be able to display the contents of my various arrays (for debugging purposes at this point), and decided to write a function to help me with that. This is what I came up with.
The goal is to be able to display any type of incoming array (int, double, etc).
Because I never had any official programming training, I am wondering if what I have is too "inelegant" and could be improved by doing something obvious to a good computer science person, but not so to a layperson.

```
int
DisplayArrayInDebugWindow(
void**              incoming_array,
char*               array_type_str,
int                 array_last_index_dim_size,
int                 array_terminator,
HWND                handle_to_display_window,
wchar_t*            optional_array_name     ) 
{

wchar_t             message_bufferw[1000];
    message_bufferw[0] =                                                        L'\0';
wchar_t             temp_buffer[400];
if ( array_last_index_dim_size == 0 ) { array_last_index_dim_size =             1; }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Processing for "int" type array
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (    0 == (strcmp( array_type_str, "int" ))  )
{

    int             j =                                                         0;
    swprintf( temp_buffer,                                                      L"%s\r\n", optional_array_name );
    wcscat( message_bufferw,                                                    temp_buffer );
    for ( int i = 0; ((int)(*((int*)( (int)incoming_array + i * (int)sizeof(int) * array_last_index_dim_size + j * (int)sizeof(int))))) != array_terminator; i++ )
    {
        swprintf( temp_buffer, L"%02i:\t", i );
        wcscat( message_bufferw,                                                temp_buffer );
        for ( j; j < last_array_dim_size; j++ )
        {
            swprintf( temp_buffer, L"%i\t", ((int)(*((int*)( (int)incoming_array + i  * (int)sizeof(int) * array_last_index_dim_size + j * (int)sizeof(int) )))) ); //
            wcscat( message_bufferw,                                            temp_buffer );
        }   
        wcscat( message_bufferw,                                                L"\r\n" );

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        // reset j to 0 each time
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------
        j =                                                                     0;
    }
    swprintf( temp_buffer,                                                      L"\nEnd of Array\n" );
    wcscat( message_bufferw,                                                    temp_buffer );
    SetWindowText( handle_to_display_window, message_bufferw );
}


return 0;
}
```

NB: When I pass in "incoming array", I type cast it as (void**) obviously.

Comment: C or C++? In C++ you can use templates to remove a lot of the complexity.

Comment: I *really* hope that this is not meant to be C++ code. Please remove one of the tags, the two different languages call for different answers.

Comment: Also what's with your formatting - why is it in two columns?

Comment: If code is working, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be appropriated.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for pointing this out. I don't really know what the difference is-except that c is a subset of c++ and that I don't yet use things like "classes" and whatever else that c++ introduced. However, I "compile as c++", if that makes sense, and, therefore, I don't mind starting to introduce c++ ways into my code, if it makes sense, which, judging by one of the answers, it does. I am formatting with columns because after years of making my code "fit within 80 characters", I realized it's not working for me. I have 1080p display and plenty of real estate to improve my experience.

Comment: @Jarod42 I did not know about codereview. Yes, this code is working, but it seems exceptionally cumbersome.

Comment: @a1s2d3f4 "c is a subset of c++" Not even this holds, you cannot compile C code as C++ in general (`restrict`, different type conversion rules, etc.). C and C++ are two different languages, and most C code that compiles as C++ is still horrible C++, even if it happens to be correct. For example, the `malloc` family is quite a dangerous class of functions in C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You are scaring me, because my program has plenty of mallocs and I was hoping that it would be a smooth transition to eventually start using c++ constructs as I discover their usefulness for my code. As a self-trained programmer I really appreciate any explanations (or pointers) as to why things should be done one way and not the other by those who know what they are doing.

Comment: @a1s2d3f4 Concerning `malloc`: Many classes in C++ must run a special member function called constructor before being useable. `malloc` does not do this -> potential source for trouble. Many people handle this with `new` and `delete`, which works, but is not modern C++ either because it violates the important RAII concept. Tbh I would not start to mix C++ and C code. Just learn C++ from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and keep compiling your C code as C. You can later on access the C functions from your C++ translation units.

Answer (score 0):

When the data type changes but the algorithm doesn't, it's time to consider using templates.

```
template<class Element_Type>
print_array(Element_Type const * p_begin,
            Element_Type const * p_end)
{
  while (p_begin != p_end)
  {
    cout << *p_begin;
    ++p_begin;
  }
}
```

The conversion from single dimension to multiple dimension is left as an exercise to the OP and readers.

**Edit 1:  Another alternative**
At some point, the output function will need information about how to print the information you gave it.

One option is for you to write your own `printf` function that has format specifiers for the data you send it.

While another option is to pass a pointer to a function that prints the data.

The fundamental issue is that the output function needs to know how to print the data.

For C++, I suggest overriding `operator<<` in the class / structure.  Since the class/structure knows the data, it can easily know how to print the data.

Comment: I have not yet gotten comfortable with implementing classes and templates and all these other c++ things, but it appears that your c++ based solution is a lot simpler than what i have, suggesting it makes sense to spend some time browsing online. I'll need to figure out what Element_Type. Browsing online is not giving me anything when I search for "class Element_Type". Is p_end what I call my "array_terminator"?

Comment: Since C and C++ are strongly typed language, you will need to pass information about the type to the printing function; otherwise the printing function will not know how to print the data (variable) you gave it.  Another option is to pass a function pointer or function object that handles the printing for the given object.

Comment: @a1s2d3f4 `Element_Type` is just an arbitrary name chosen by Thomas. The interesting part is the `template <class (...)>`. But I highly recommend learning C++ systematically, not bit by bit from the internet.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for the suggestions. To wrap up this discussion, if I were to stick with "C" (meaning no classes/templates), is there a more elegant way for this function than what I have, or is this a clear example of the advantage of C++ over C?